# Probability of throwing exactly 5 pairs, with sum larger or equal to 6, in 9 dice (2 dices) throws.

Tags: probability

If I throw two dice 9 times, what is the probability of throwing exactly 5 pairs, where sum of two dice are equal/larger than 6?

So far I have got, that:

- **B**-in 1 throw, a pair of sum larger/equal to 6 is thrown
- $P(B)=\frac{(36-10)}{36}=\frac{26}{36}$

So figured out that $P(A)$ would be calculated this way:

$P(A)=\frac{26\cdot25\cdot...\cdot 18}{36^9}=0.011$

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $P(B)$ is right but you've computed $P(A)$ incorrectly.  Think of P(B) as the probability of success, and then the probability of failure is $1-P(B)$.  Then you have a Bernoulli process with 9 trials.  Do you know how many ways can you have 5 successes, and what the probability of 5 successes is in a Bernoulli trial?

Comment: Ouu, so the probability of getting sum that is larger/equal than 6, in next throw, is constant and does not change during trials, right?

Comment: that's right, so you can count the number of ways to do this 5 times, and then multiply by $P(B)^5(1-P(B))^4$

Answer (score 0):

Choose $5$ out of $9$ pairs with sum $\geq6$, and $4$ out of the remaining $4$ pairs with sum $<6$.

So the probability is:

$$\binom{9}{5}\cdot\left(\frac{26}{36}\right)^5\cdot\binom{4}{4}\cdot\left(\frac{10}{36}\right)^4\approx14.74\%$$